# How to fire a Service every 2 minutes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm doing a bluetooth scan event every 2 minutes to check if a specific device is nearby and can be detected through bluetooth. It's a service as I want it to run in the background.

I would like to know why setRepeat fluctuates after some time, the longest interval was 10 minutes. I'm setting it to fire every 2 minutes.

```
 var intent = Intent(context, Alarm::class.java);
        var am = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        intent.action = "from.alarm.clock";
        var pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 1000 * 60 * 2, getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0))
```

****UPDATE****

Still haven't found the best answer for this problem.

Comment: What version are you using? According to this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent) Alarms are inexact starting with api19. The impact should not be 500% but it might be an issue nonetheless

Comment: Android 7. Will look into it

Comment: Try with PeriodicWorkRequest (Its reliable and internally uses Alarm manager or Job scheduler based on android API LEVEL)


https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-workmanager#0 (code sample)

Comment: @BeingHuman I will look into this. Thank you

Comment: @BeingHuman per the documentation, "Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes."

What I need is every 2 mins

Comment: @rboyg Yes u r right, I missed that point , Let me check how to achieve the same using jobService

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an Alarm receiver that triggers exactly 2 minutes by recursive call. Android does not allow frequent precise wakeup calls as it might drain battery faster. This is a workaround to get your calls triggered in exact intervals.

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class NotificationAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    public static final long PING_FREQ = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
        initNotification(context);
    }

    private void initNotification(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIndent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NotificationAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + PING_FREQ, pIndent);
    }
}
```

Refer this site and you will get a good idea on how to use Boradcast to get periodic calls to a service. [Reference codepath.com](http:////%20https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks)

Comment: Should I still call the setRepeat on the activity calling the broadcast or should I just call it inside the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: In your starting activity, you start this service. Then it will call itself recursively by the set interval. I do not know who downvoted it or why. You may accept this as answer or find one and provide for others.

Comment: I will try this and let you know